# How are system calls dealt with in a multicore Linux system?

Tags: linux-kernel

When a thread or process from one core initiates a system call(ex. it can be fork()), the OS goes into kernel mode, assuming that multiple systems calls(ex. maybe also fork()) come in from different cores, how does the OS deal with this? Does the OS use a global lock and only allow only one call to be active in kernel mode? Or the OS allow process the system call concurrently except a very minor portion which is a critical section?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the OS and on its version. All Linux kernels in use, however, are reentrant and can be called several times not just from different CPUs but even from different threads on the same CPU. They use fine-grained locks instead of global ones. (However, see also [Big Kernel Lock](http://kernelnewbies.org/BigKernelLock), which wasn't *fully* removed until 2011.)

- https://www.quora.com/Is-the-Linux-kernel-re-entrant
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393650/how-does-the-linux-kernel-realize-reentrancy
- http://www.tldp.org/FAQ/Threads-FAQ/Reentrancy.html

FreeBSD (which has its own "Giant lock"):

- https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/bsdcon02/full_papers/baldwin/baldwin.pdf

Comment: Really appreciated your answer. It helped me a lot. Anyway, I feel I'm dreaming. it is amazing and I can't believe that I got the answer in an hour from whom that I didn't know. Thank you so much Grawity.